# is it possible that mysql_real_escape_string($str) is empty when $str is not empty

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand whether `mysql_real_escape_string($str)` can be empty if `$str` is not empty (by `$str` is empty I mean that `empty($str)` is `true`)?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` will be empty if you are not connected to a database.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Rocket No it will not return empty string, instead it will be `FALSE` of boolean type

Comment: @AlvinWong: If he was trying to use it as a string, the `FALSE` would be converted to a string.  `echo FALSE` will echo nothing.

Comment: @Alvin Depends on how you define "empty". If you define it with the `empty()` function, i.e. `== false`, then both an "empty string" and `false` are "empty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `mysql_real_escape_string`
>
> Returns the escaped string, or `FALSE` on error.

So the return value is either `false` if there's an error (like not being connected to the database), which counts as "empty". Or it's the escaped string, which means that there are *additional* escape characters in the string. `mysql_real_escape_string` will not *reduce* the string.

So if the string has content and you are connected to the database, if the input is not "empty", the output won't be either. If there's an error though, the output will be "empty".